# Packing an object, its method to call and arguments to call it with into a single object for invoking it later

Tags: c++, boost

Is it possible, with C++ 11 or Boost, to create an object that stores an object pointer (instance), method pointer and some arguments and can invoke this method with these arguments later? I mean - how to do it using only std or Boost templates? I'm pretty sure it is possible, but don't know what's the best way.

And here's the real question: is it in any way possible to store several such objects that refer to different methods (with diferent signatures) in the same container?

Comment: `Is it possible, with C++ 11 or Boost, to create an object that ... ` Yes. `std::bind`, `boost::bind`.

Comment: `Is it in any way possible to store several such objects that refer to different methods (with diferent signatures) in the same container` No, not really. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: in my specific case it would allow for a very convenient inter-thread call mechanism. Create calls in worker thread, invoke in UI thread, and it doesn't have to care about signatures.

Comment: Oh, well if you're pre-binding all the arguments, then that's fine. Because the resulting functor will have _zero_ arguments and a _void_ return type; doesn't matter that the _actual_ function being called has arguments, because you already bound them. Yes, this is a common approach.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: great, that's the part I was missing! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the classic use case for `std::bind` and `std::function`:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using namespace std::placeholders;   // for _1, _2, ...

std::vector<std::function<int(double, char)>> v;

Foo x;
Bar y;

v.emplace_back(std::bind(&Foo::f, &x, _1, _2));         // int Foo::f(double, char)
v.emplace_back(std::bind(&Bar::g, &y, _2, true, _1));   // int Bar::g(char, bool, double)
v.emplace_bacK(some_free_function);                     // int some_free_function(double, char)
```

To use:

```
for (auto & f : v) { sum += f(1.5, 'a'); }
```

Comment: Your `Foo::f` example is slightly broken (wrong number of arguments).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Ugh, I always wish that would work :-S

Comment: You mean the placeholders being auto-bound when not given?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes. It feels like something that should obviously work... Does it work with `boost::bind` perhaps? I always feel like I've seen that somewhere.

Comment: No, not to my knowledge. (Nor in my experience, to the best of my memory.)

Answer (score 3):

Check out [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) offered by C++11. It does exactly what you want. You don't even need boost for this. For example:

```
class C
{
public:
  void Foo(int i);
}

C c;

// Create a function object to represent c.Foo(5)
std::function<void(void)> callLater=std::bind(&C::Foo,std::ref(c),5);

// Then later when you want to call c.Foo(5), you do:
callLater();
```

Comment: But can I store different function objects in the same container?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe The resulting object can be easily stored in a [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). If the function objects all have the same signature, you could make a container for them, e.g., `std::vector<std::function<void()>>`.

Comment: .. but not if they don't.

Comment: You cannot easily store function objects of different types in the same container. Also, you cannot compare function objects with each other, except to test if they are both empty or not.

Comment: Ah yes the OP is binding _all_ the parameters, so the key here is that an expression `callLater()` really is all that's required (which has the corollary of homogeneous storage). +1